# Disable Hover effect in KivyMD dataTable

Tags: python, frontend, kivy, mouseevent, kivymd

I have provided here a simple example of a datatable and I would like to disable the highlighting effect as a result of mouse hover.

```
    import os
    os.environ['KIVY_GL_BACKEND'] = 'angle_sdl2'
    from kivy.metrics import dp
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivymd.app import MDApp
    from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
    
    
    class DynamicTableExample(MDApp):
        def build(self):
            layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    
            # Create a data table with custom cell height
            table = MDDataTable(
                #background_color_header="#65275d",
                #background_color_cell="#451938",
                #background_color_selected_cell="#451938",
                size_hint=(1, 1),
                use_pagination=True,
                check=True,
                column_data=[
                    ("Header 1", dp(50)),  # Adjust the width as needed
                    ("Header 2", dp(50)),
                    ("Header 3", dp(50)),
                ],
                row_data=[
                    ("This is a long text for Row 1 Data 1.\n " * 5, "This is a long text for without next line This is a long text for without next line This is a long text for without next line This is a long text for without next line ", "This is a long text for Row 1 Data 3"),
                    ("51", "28", "387"),
                    ("58", "42", "78"),
                ]
            )
    
            layout.add_widget(table)
    
            return layout
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        DynamicTableExample().run()
```

I would like to do this to increase the performance as much as possible.